# Using History.js to recall filter state

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, state, history.js

I have a page with a list of cars, each with different properties (brand, model, color, country of origin, etc.) stored as HTML class values, for instance:

`<li class="car honda civic blue japan">Honda Civic</li>`.

I've created some javascript filters that use these classes to narrow down the list (i.e. Only show `<li>`s that have `blue` or `japan` as a class), but when a user navigates to another page and hits the "Back" button in their browser, the filters are reset.

I'm unclear on how to tell [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js) to store the applied filters (in this case `blue` and `japan`) and re-apply them when a user clicks the browser's Back button.

```
<script>
  (function(window,undefined){
    // Establish Variables
    var State = History.getState();

    // Bind to State Change
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
      var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    });

    // I want to save the state of the filters every time a new one is clicked
    $(".filter a").click(function() {
      var myState += $(this).class() + " "; // This will just be a string of all the applied filters
      history.pushState(myState, viewModel.title, viewModel.url);
    });

  })(window);
</script>
```